# Импорт текста в алерт из массива (Swift)

Tags: массивы, ios, swift, xcode, alert

Проблема заключается в следующем: Нужно вывести в Алерт message из массива , Гугл не помог , решил обратиться к профессионалам)

```
 import UIKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

let reminders =                 [Reminder(message: "Let's break", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 1),
                                 Reminder(message: "Please , stop", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 2),
                                 Reminder(message: "Chill out", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 3)]
    
   
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
```

Массив заиничен в другом классе

```
class Reminder {
var message: String
var days: Int
var hours: Int
var minutes: Int

init(message: String, days:Int ,hours:Int , minutes: Int) {
    self.message = message
    self.days = days
    self.hours = hours
    self.minutes = minutes
```

Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала нужно обратится к нужному индексу массива, в вашем примере длина массива равняется 3, то есть у вас три экземпляра Reminder, обратимся к примеру к 0 индексу, то есть к первому объекту в вашем массиве

```
let reminder = reminders[0]
```

Далее из объекта reminder мы получаем нужную нам переменную, message

```
let message = reminder.message
```

затем передаем ее как параметр в AlertViewController, итоговый код:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

UPD1: нужно переопределить метод загрузки вашего контроллера вот так

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

и уже добавить код в него

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let reminder = reminders[0]
        let message = reminder.message
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

В данном примере используется DispatchQueue.main.async, чтобы отобразить при загрузке ViewController'a alert, иначе можно добавить UI элемент который по клику или какому то действию будет вызывать отображение вашего алерта

полный листинг кода для вашего вопроса

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let reminders =                 [Reminder(message: "Let's break", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 1),
    Reminder(message: "Please , stop", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 2),
    Reminder(message: "Chill out", days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 3)]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let reminder = reminders[0]
        let message = reminder.message
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

ПС, глубоко в причины написания DispatchQueue.main.async я не буду увлекаться это не много другая тема

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но , увы , выдает ошибку "Cannot use instance member 'reminders' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Comment: добавил комментарии по вашему вопросу